# .NET Core Max Pool Size Reached

Tags: max, size, pool

Core newbie here...the company I work for just updated our old ASP.NET MVC site to a .NET Core site. It is hosted on load-balanced AWS platform and uses EF Core Power Tools to interact with our SQL Server database.

Since launch, we have been experiencing random outages where the max connection pool size is being hit. Whenever we have an outage, we are seeing this in the logs:

Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

We use a context factory wrapped in a using to create the db connection:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3eXh.png)

At this time, we are working on setting up performance monitoring, but any other suggestions of what we should be doing to prevent the connection leaks would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using asyn method then you should use await will. And there is no need to Close the Connection as **using** will handle the disposal.

You can update the code as below :

```
    using (var db = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
{
    var result = (await db.procedures.Profile_Get_ByUserIdAsync(userId)).Result.FirstOrDefault().ToProfileUserInfo();
    return result;
}
```

If still you are getting the max pool error then you can try to add max pool size in your db connection or data source as below :

```
"Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydb;User Id=myuser;Password=mypassword;Max Pool Size=100;"
```

Next time please post your code as text, not as a image.